# VPN server (beachhead) without root?

Tags: vpn, ssh-tunneling

How can I set up a VPN server on a host where I don't have root?

I have the following constraints:

- On the server A, I have no root. I can only operate in my home directory. In particular, I also cannot create `tun` devices.
- On the client B, I have complete control and can install what I want.
- SSH port forwarding (-L/-R) and SOCKS proxy (-D) works, but not in my case. The software on my client uses many different ports so I'd be inclined to use SOCKS, but it also runs at kernel level, so I can't convince it with `tsocks` to use the proxy. One thing that would work would by to run my client software in a VM on B, and socksify the whole VM - but I'd really rather not go that route.
- I don't need priviliged ports, so non-root on A should be OK.
- It doesn't have to be a "real" VPN, but something similar in spirit would be enough. My process on B should be able to communicate with processes on A (and connected devices) as if they were on one machine, without rewriting them.

I don't believe there is an elegant way to do this - the *correct* way would be to just ask the admin of A, or plug B into the same net - but now I'm just curious if this can be done as a proof of concept.

Answer (score 8):

Well, this "I have no root" access on Server A can be a problem to create a good VPN solution since:

- [ip-ip tunneling](http://lartc.org/howto/lartc.tunnel.ip-ip.html) requires interface manipulation;
- [pptp](http://marc.info/?l=pptpclient-devel&m=107267602717385&w=3) also requires root privileges to create interfaces;
- [OpenVPN](https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/UnprivilegedUser) can even run as unprivileged user, but some tricks need to be done like allowing sudo to the `ip` command to allow the creation of `tun` interface;
- [strongSwan](https://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/ReducedPrivileges) with reduced privileges requires `CAP_NET_ADMIN` or `CAP_NET_RAW` to work, and running IKE daemon as non-root user breaks support for iptables updown script.

What remains to you my friend: Rely on [SSH socks proxy](http://embraceubuntu.com/2006/12/08/ssh-tunnel-socks-proxy-forwarding-secure-browsing/). On your local machine, and as root, run:

```
ssh -C2qTnN -D 8080 username@serverA
```

**Means**: *Compression, SSH2 only, Quiet, Force pseudo-tty allocation, Redirect stdin from /dev/null, and Place the ssh client into "master" mode for connection sharing.*

Now, all you have to do is to run your application. If it has native SOCKSv5 support like Firefox, it's just a matter of configuring "localhost:8080" as the proxy server.

If your application does not support this proxy natively, run it with [proxychains](http://proxychains.sourceforge.net/). Just install on your client and you are good to go.

The only solution you don't want to adopt seems to be the only one, unfortunately.

Links:

- [Proxy Firefox through a SSH tunnel](https://calomel.org/firefox_ssh_proxy.html)